# how to show videoview in recycleview with thumbail in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am implementing video view in recycleview with thumbnails after click on video view list to play particular view in next window.

But thumbnail is not showing and videos automatically start, I don't know how to do this.

Any one know about how is it possible? Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is related to layout.

Create a video_playing_with_thumbnail.xml

```
        Add this in layout xml

        ****
           <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_video"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="9">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/laywork"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="7"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <VideoView
                                android:id="@+id/displayer"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/listphotosrecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
          </RelativeLayout>

     </FrameLayout>
 ****


for thumbnail showing in recyclerView you can do:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                     />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/deleteVideo"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cross_"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create a custom adapter class to click on thumbnail and show in big one view.

Comment: i define on recycleview in activity and define custom layout for item(videoview,imageview)

Comment: i want to implement recyclewview like youtube player click on view show full view

Comment: u want to saying create videoview with recycleview and customelist item view